# How to create an array of empty lists?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I'm struggling a bit with NumPy's build in arrays.

I have a list with values:

```
l = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

The `len(l)` of the list is 5 and I want to create an array with the following structure.

```
array = [[][][][][]]
```

The inner array amount should be the length of the list `l`. (5)

Is there any solution to this with NumPy or is there a solution doing this with the build in list from python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using python:

```
array = [[] for _ in range(len(l))]
```

Output: `[[], [], [], [], []]`

With numpy:

```
array = np.zeros(shape=(len(l), 0))
```

Output: `array([], shape=(5, 0), dtype=float64)` (this is the same as `np.array([[], [], [], [], []])`)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you also know a way to do this with a list so I can use .append(value) on for example array[0] or array[1].

Comment: @LordLazor not sure to understand, can you provide an explicit input/output example?

Comment: Edo Wexler solved my question already in the answer below.

Comment: @LordLazor I'm confused, Edo use the exact same approach as mine in the first part (`array = [[] for _ in range(len(l))]`)

Comment: Oh sorry I have overseen your first solution. Both of you could present me the best solution. Sorry for the confusion. :)

Answer (score 1):

With bulit in list:

```
n = 5
arr = [[] for x in range(n)]
arr
```